# image uploading is not working in php

Tags: php, jquery, image, cakephp

I am working on image uploader in cakephp. I have used this link "http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/thumbnail-image-upload-ajaxphp/#comment-10823"  to display thumb images when user clicks the browse button . Everything is working fine in fire fox but not working in other browsers(IE, chrome). This is because File properties ( i.e type, tmp_name, name) were not submitted when user clicks the submit button. Below is my code for image uploading

```
 <?php

  echo $form->create('imageupload');
echo $form->input('image_browse',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false, 'size'=>23, 'type'=>'file','class'=>'image_browse','id'=>'image_browse','onChange'=>'javascript:previewImage(this.value)));
    echo $form->submit();?>
```

In my controller, i am using the var_dump($_FILES); to see the file parameters, but it is giving following output.

```
array
  'image_browse' => 
array
  'name' => string '' (length=0)
  'type' => string '' (length=0)
  'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'error' => int 4
  'size' => int 0
```

Even though i gave the proper image path, it is giving file not uploaded error. If i remove the js file link used to display thumbs, it is working good. But i want to display thumb as well as upload the file.
How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance
Pushpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Hey Buddy!

Start the form as:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('imageupload', array('type' => 'file'));
?>
```

and after that create input elements

Comment: I think I will better understand your problem if you show me more of your code. As I assume the bug might be in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem

If your $_FILES and $_POST are empty, this can be due to

- the limit set by post_max_size in php.ini
- the limit set by upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Unfortunately the first limit is not reported back as an error code in $_FILES['error'].